# Rails 3 controller from plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, controllers

I am creating a Rails 3 plugin and I want to integrate controllers in it that will be automaticly consider by rails as a "normal" controller from the app/controllers folder. How can I do that or what is the best solution for me to have custom controllers from a plugin?
I have found documentations from [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) but they have changed the documentation and plugin development doesn't include controllers anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You will need to define a class within your plugin that inherits from `Rails::Engine`. In effect, the feature you want *is an engine*.

Define the class like this:

**lib/your_thing/engine.rb**

```
module YourThing
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

You can then define your engine's controllers at `app/controllers` within that plugin and for them to work neatly you will also need to define routes for them, which you can do inside `config/routes.rb` inside the engine like this:

```
YourThing::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :things
end
```

Next, you'll need to mount your engine inside your application:

```
mount YourThing::Engine, :at => "/"
```

The application then will be able to use routes from your engine.

For more information, I'm in the progress of writing the official Rails Engine guide which [you can reference here.](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/engines.html) Please let me know if you have any further questions and I'll try to answer them in the guide.

Comment: I tried to create an engine using the plugin new generator using the option --mountable but the engine.rb file isn't created. What could be the reason? A rails version problem?

Comment: @Mika: you should be running Rails 3.1.