# app/controllers in my gem not added to autoload_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I created a Gem (a Devise extension). In this Gem I added routes served by a controller that I put under app/controllers folder. So my folder structure looks like:

```
app/
  |_ controllers/
                |_ my_pkg/my_controller.rb
lib/
   |_my_gem.rb // somewhere in this file I added the routes.
```

However, I got error when I tested it:

```
uninitialized constant MyPkg::MyController
```

My best guess is that "app/controllers" of my Gem was not added to Rails autoload_paths.

I tried several solutions and none of them works:

- changed gemspec: spec.require_paths = ["lib"] --> spec.require_paths = ["lib", "app/controllers"]
- changed gemspec: remove line: spec.platform      = Gem::Platform::RUBY  # removing this line caused "app/controllers" to appear in $LOAD_PATH. But problem was not solved.

Have been struggling with it for 12 hours straight now.... :( Any hints will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: to have rails add "app" and its subfolders to autoload_paths, you need to define an Engine and make sure your Engine class is loaded:

[Rails 3 controller from plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926115/rails-3-controller-from-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The error `uninitialized constant MyPkg::MyController` only say that module function can not be load rather that file not load.

See if your `my_controller.rb` defined as:

```
module MyOkg
  class MyController < xxx
    ....
  end
end
```

or

```
class Mypkg::MyController < xxxx
  ...
end
```